# oracle DB connection - hostdef extension doesn't exist

Tags: oracle, jdbc, erwin

I am trying to connect to an Oracle DB through ERwin, yet I keep getting this error message:

[image]

I know that the DB exists, as my coworkers are accessing it. The Username and Password are also correct, and I've had a few other coworkers try their credentials too and it didn't work.

The possible error might be with the connection string,but I've tried several options, and none seem to work. These are the options I've used:

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@DomainName.DN.DN.com:1521:DatabaseName`

Of course, I didn't actually type DomainName, I changed those from the company name. This was a direct copy of the connection string that was used in Squirrel SQL for this DB.

I also tried, based on a friend's suggestion:

`jdbc:tibcosoftwareinc:oracle://DomainName.DN.DN.com:1521;SID=DatabaseName`

This is the connection page that I'm using:

[image]

Comment: What version of Erwin are you using?

Answer (score -1):

The correct format for the connection string is:

(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = "HOST name")(PORT = "PORT number")) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = "SERVICE Name") ) )